# using sql LIMIT 1 on specific queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, limit

I was wondering if is more memory-efficient to include LIMIT 1 on queries
when we expect 1 result at all times.

So for example I have the following query

```
select * from clients where client_id = x
```

I don't have extensive db management skills but I'm assuming that

```
select * from clients where client_id = x limit 1
```

would be a bit more memory efficient because the query
wont have to iterate thru each row on the table once it finds
that row.

Am I right or it doesn't matter if I include limit in this specific case?

Comment: Try it and see if one or second query is faster or not.

Comment: If  `client_id` is a`primary key` then it'll never be repeated so there's no need to use `limit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *could* make a big difference if you do not have an index.

Consider the following with no index:

```
select *
from clients
where client_id = x
```

The engine will need to scan the *entire* table to determine that there is only one row.  With `limit 1` it could stop at the first match.

However, if you have an index, then the index would have the information for equality comparisons.  So, the limit would not make a difference in terms of performance.  There might be some slight difference, but it should be negligible.

Comment: I have an index (client_id) is primary key

Comment: @user3772 . . . Hence, it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If client_id is primary index means, no need to use LIMIT 1. Because it will not more effective.